# Creation of custom event for standard table AGR_USERS in SAP

Tags: event-handling, abap, user-roles, sap-basis

How to create custom event on standard table (`AGR_USERS`) whenever a new entry is created/inserted in the table.

**My input**

I have tried creating custom event using Transaction code `SWEC` by copying an object type `ARBCIGUSER` but when I am assigning roles to a user that event is not getting triggered in `SWEL` Tcode.

Following this blog : https://blogs.sap.com/2013/07/16/custom-event-creation-by-using-change-document-concept/

Not sure if it is the right way to create custom event for standard table. Also where to write the custom logic inside the event.

Tcode used : `SU01` to assign roles to user.

Comment: How is it linked to SAP BusinessObjects? (which is Business Intelligence software, there's no relationship with `AGR_USERS` table used in ABAP-based software)

Comment: Not business object but business type ,I have corrected the question .Also attaching the screenshot for the creation of custom event which i did after following the blog : https://blogs.sap.com/2013/07/16/custom-event-creation-by-using-change-document-concept/ .I have used below in SWEC: Change doc object : PFCG(assuming this is the right one for roles assignment) Business obj type : ZARBCIGUSER(custom copied from ARBCIGUSER).Kindly suggest if there is any alternate way to raise event whenever any change in role assignment for users(Table: AGR_USERS)

Comment: Thanks. I have removed the SAP BusinessObjects tag (look at each tag info to choose tags adequately).

Comment: The way to do this is to find what standard events are triggered when you save a user.
Given Central user management users IDOCS to keep things in sync there must be triggered somewhere.  At a minimum it is the trigger of IDOC:
If BO Event is triggered , you will see an event in the event log.
Turn that on using SWELS  then check the events in SWEL  :
At least USER.<event> is expected.

Comment: I am yet to check on the standard event , but if the standard event exists ,how to customise the standard event ?